# Chosen JavaScript List Update

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Chosen for a select box on a website and I want to have the list dynamically updated based on the text being typed. The change event only happens after the item is selected. Does anyone know how I can retrieve the text when it is changed?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gllowmas/RV4z3/13/)

Comment: An example of what you have thus far on jsFiddle will be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks For the suggestion Tyler. I have linked what I've attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of change event use keyup event.